# Using NuGet in Rider without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider without having Visual Studio installed.
I have installed Visual Studio Build Tools to compile my code.
The NuGet package manager in Rider still doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Is there any way to fix that without installing Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Check the feeds or Sources, if there are any

Answer (score 7):

Please, check your NuGet sources on "Sources" tab in NuGet tool window. Maybe you have disabled nuget.org feed. On "Sources" you can find [Effective NuGet.Config] option it is current state your feeds for your current project.